# What is an in-memory Http server?

Tags: asp.net, server, integration-testing

When implementing integration tests for an ASP.NET CORE application, I came across the term "In-Memory Server", apparently this is a specific type of HTTP server intended for ASP.NET application integration tests.

I would like to understand what would be this "Server in Memory" and what is the difference between this type of server and a traditional server?

Comment: in-memory = on your local computer, blazing fast startup time, minimal/zero configuration, and no permanent storage of data. Probably very little security as well. Traditional servers = can be run on a dedicated machine, VM, or cloud service, may have configuration requirements, can persist data changes, can be hardened for security.

Comment: You're looking for the TestHost https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0